# Error installing awscli using pip (macOS)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to install Amazon's awscli onto my mac, and I am running into a few errors that I'm not able to diagnose.  I've followed all the steps so far in [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html), but when I actually try to install awscli, it gives me the following error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awscli (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awscli
```

The full trace of what is happening is

```
bash-3.2$ ./Library/Python/2.7/bin/pip install awscli --upgrade --user
Collecting awscli
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0d4390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)': /simple/awscli/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0d4890>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)': /simple/awscli/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0d4d10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)': /simple/awscli/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0d4d50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)': /simple/awscli/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b0d4690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',)': /simple/awscli/
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement awscli (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for awscli
```

I'm almost 100% sure that there is a connection error to the resource I am trying to install, but since the command comes directly from Amazon, it shouldn't be outdated? Also, I am running pip version 9.0.1, so there shouldn't be an out of date issue.

Comment: [This page](https://anaconda.org/pypi/awscli) suggests a more complete path. Can you try that?

Comment: can you try this command `pip install awscli --ignore-installed six`

Comment: Im still having this issue. Any luck on your end?

Comment: @CBP, this is an issue with your machine, not pip or amazon. I blame the contents of your hosts file: `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Hope this helps other people who encounter this issue.

```
brew install python3    
pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user
```

Comment: this involves replacing the stock Python with Homebrew Python, and does not address the actual problem in the question

Comment: Fair, but I was getting the exact same error as @user3334871 while trying to install the aws cli. This resolved my issue and could potentially unblock others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to follow the other set of instructions there:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

> Install the AWS CLI Using the Bundled Installer
>
> Follow these steps from the command line to install the AWS CLI using
>   the bundled installer.
>
> To install the AWS CLI using the bundled installer
>
> Download the AWS CLI Bundled Installer.
>
> ```
> $ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
> ```
>
> Unzip the package.
>
> ```
> $ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
> ```
>
> Note
>
> If you don't have unzip, use your Linux distribution's built in package manager to install it.
>
> Run the install executable.
>
> ```
> $ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
> ```
>
> Note
>
> By default, the install script runs under the system default version of Python. If you have installed an alternative version of
>   Python and want to use that to install the AWS CLI, run the install
>   script with that version by absolute path to the Python executable.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> $ sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
> ```
>
> The installer installs the AWS CLI at /usr/local/aws and creates the
>   symlink aws at the /usr/local/bin directory. Using the -b option to
>   create a symlink eliminates the need to specify the install directory
>   in the user's $PATH variable. This should enable all users to call the
>   AWS CLI by typing aws from any directory.
>
> To see an explanation of the -i and -b options, use the -h option:
>
> ```
> $ ./awscli-bundle/install -h
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest way is to just install it with `conda`;

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/awscli

You can use some commands like this:

```
$ wget "https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64.sh"
$ bash "Miniconda3-4.5.4-MacOSX-x86_64.sh" -b -p "${PWD}/conda"
$ source "${PWD}/conda/bin/activate"
(base) $ conda config --add channels conda-forge
(base) $ conda install -y -c conda-forge awscli=1.16.29
(base) $ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.29 Python/3.6.5 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.12.19
```

The caveat is that you will need to use this `conda` installation whenever you need to use the AWS CLI, but its easier than messing with system-wide installations or pip configs, IMO, and `conda` is more robust than a Python virtual env.

Answer (score 0):

Facing similar error while installing awscli on my mac machine(Mojave version).
Followed below steps to resolve it.

1. Try to install awscli using brew.

   ```
   brew install awscli
   ```
2. Reference link :

   https://vyspiansky.github.io/2018/03/17/install-aws-cli-on-macos/

   This link helped me. Hope this helps!!.